# AutoCad rotate command with AutoLisp

Tags: autocad, autolisp

I want to create a simple "rotate" command with AutoLisp, so this is the code I wrote:

```
(defun C:myfunc()
    (setq p1 (getpoint "\nPick first POINT on the screen:\n"))
    (setq p2 (getpoint "\nPick second POINT on the screen:\n"))

    (command "line" p1 p2 "") 
    (setq ss1 (ssget p2)) 
    (command "rotate" ss1 p2 "90" "")
    (princ )
)
```

I insert two points, p1 and p2 and create a line which connects them. After that I create the ss1 object which is the line p1-p2. Finally I attempt to rotate the line from base point p2 for 90 degrees.

I insert the code in AutoCad, but instead of creating the rotated line, it asks to insert manually the base point as well as the angle, so I guess that there is a problem with the `command "rotate" ...` line.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: As a side note, [entlast](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/search-result/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2016/ENU/AutoCAD-AutoLISP/files/GUID-75DBA9B2-034B-4377-A4E2-21D37B298D86-htm.html) will return the last object. This could prevent problems if you have multiple objects at `p2`.

Comment: It's been a while since I've worked with AutoLisp, but should your `"90"` instead be `90`?

Comment: @ crashmstr Several tutorials use `"90"`, none uses `90`.

Comment: I found some examples and wrote up an answer that should help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I've seen online, you have two problems.

`ROTATE` does not take a selection set but an entity name
Missing an extra `""` before the rotation point.

```
(defun C:myfunc()
    (setq p1 (getpoint "\nPick first POINT on the screen:\n"))
    (setq p2 (getpoint "\nPick second POINT on the screen:\n"))

    (command "line" p1 p2 "") 
    (setq ss1 (ssget p2)) 
    (command "rotate" (entlast) "" p2 "90")
    (princ )
)
```

Reference: [AutoLISP: Rotate Multiple Objects Around Their Base Point](https://autocadtips1.com/2014/02/01/autolisp-rotate-multiple-objects-around-their-base-point/)

As a side note, it usually helps me to try the command manually to make sure you are responding to all the correct prompts with the correct data/values.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the following simplified code:

```
(defun c:myfunc ( / p1 p2 )
    (if
        (and
            (setq p1 (getpoint "\nPick first POINT on the screen:"))
            (setq p2 (getpoint "\nPick second POINT on the screen:" p1))
        )
        (command "_.line" "_non" p1 "_non" p2 "" "_.rotate" (entlast) "" "_non" p2 90)
    )
    (princ)
)
```

This accounts for null user input at the prompts, uses a rubber-band for the second point prompt, allows for active Object Snap modes when supplying the point arguments to the commands (through the use of "_non"), and also allows for non-English versions of AutoCAD (through the use of an underscore), and potentially redefined commands (through the use of the "." command prefix).

This could be further improved by temporarily setting the CMDECHO system variable to 0 to suppress command-line echoing.